# How to create a DIV for each 5 elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make that for each 5 elements, I have one div. You can see here an example: http://www.nobregamedia.com/aa/

At the bottom, I have a gallery with 5 elements, changeables by the orange little squares. Each orange square has a "link" to a DIV name, For example: DIV1, DIV2, DIV3. I need to create this automatically, taking into account the amount of items I pulled from the MySQL database.

For example: If I pull 7 items, it creates 2 squares, and 2 divs: DIV1 and DIV2. And so on, in multiples of 5.

Here the code I have right now:

```
<div class="idTabs">
  <div class="col2">
    <a href="#pduno"><img class="pdimg" src="img/pduno.png" width="13" height="11" /></a>
    <a href="#pddos"><img class="pdimg" src="img/pddos.png" width="13" height="11" /></a>
    <a href="#pdtres"><img class="pdimg" src="img/pddos.png" width="13" height="11" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row-end">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col101">
    <div id="pduno">
      <table width="920" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="text-align:left">
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <?PHP
                            while ($retdetsfinal = mysql_fetch_row($retdest)) {
                        ?>
            <td height="110">
              <div style="width:160px; height:112px; border:2px solid #c0bdb6">
                <img src="imagenes/thumbs/<?php echo $retdetsfinal[0];?>_x.jpg" style="border:6px solid #FFF;" width="148" height="100" />
              </div>
              <br />
              <?php echo ucfirst($retdetsfinal[1]);?> -
              <?php echo ucfirst($retdetsfinal[2]);?><br />Bs.
              <?php echo $retdetsfinal[3];?>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <?PHP   
                        }
                        ?>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a little bit more code or a fiddle would be nice. but as I understand correctly you have for example 12 images, then you have 3 small squares changing the visible div and 3 divs in which the image items are... is that correct?

Comment: @TobiasKrogh Yes, you are right.. I think that the correct word is "wrap" the elements. Any idea.?? Thanks.!

Comment: you need to combine [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) with [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/). I don't think you will get detailed answer without some code

Answer (score 0):

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhUW3/). although it might not exactly fit your needs and of course no styling is available it should give you the correct hints to start with that